# reusability user controls of Xaml in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying a new approach i.e. XAML to make application in xamarin.forms. At this time i am facing an issue to reuse my stack layout which is having a image and label. How i can reuse my layout in different pages using XAML.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can actually define your custom component in a separate XAML file and then just link the component wherever you need it.

For example a label with image can be grouped together in a dedicated XAML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<StackLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="UserControls.ImageWithTitle"
             VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" >
    <Label HorizontalOptions="Center"
           x:Name="TitleLabel" />
    <Image Source="noimage.png" />
</StackLayout>
```

On the .cs file I've defined a binding for the TitleLabel

```cs
public string TitleName
{
     get { return TitleLabel.Text; }
     set { TitleLabel.Text = value; }
}
```

So when you include the component on another layout, you can assign the label value directly (or via a binding):

```xml
 <usercontrols:ImageWithTitle TitleName="Home"/>
```